# Screen record software for Android (unrooted Kit Kat)

Tags: android, screen-recording

I'm looking for screen recording software for my phone (Android 4.4.2). I am aware of [Android Authority's list](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-screen-recording-apps-600838/), but can't/won't use their choices because (*deep breath*)

- their top choice, [AZ Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free), is incompatible with my
  phone.
- I tried [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) (which would have been great, because
  I don't use it otherwise and can't uninstall it), but [only works with Lollipop and up](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6274965?hl=en).
- [Mobizen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mvagent)'s English skills [scared me off](https://twitter.com/MTL_Shokhet/status/829153407265099776).
- I downloaded [Stream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sparc.stream&rdid=com.sparc.stream), but there doesn't appear to be an option for recording the screen, just something that shares live camera (could be a Kit Kat problem). Anyway, I'd rather not use this because I don't want to upload a recording in order to make one.
- [Vyzor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.vysor) requires a desktop machine to record.

I would like something that's trustworthy because apps like these typically require a lot of permissions; that's what made me skittish about Mobizen. My phone is **not** rooted, and runs Android Kit Kat (4.4.2).

Comment: Unfortunately, most [Screen Recording](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_screenrecording) apps will require either Android 5+ or root. I know of no exception to that.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks. According to the linked article, [Mobizen is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5tTP.jpg). I'm considering just using it despite my unease because Android Authority trusts them enough to recommend them.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Shokhet – just added it to my list with a remark. Once you've tried it, please let us know if it suffices. If it does, consider self-answering as well :)

Comment: @Izzy It does work; [answer below](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/39348/7730) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've gotten over my reluctance at using Mobizen because, [as Izzy pointed out](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39334/screen-record-software-for-android-unrooted-kit-kat?noredirect=1#comment56787_39334), screen recorders that require neither Android 5+ or root are rare, and if Android Authority trusted them enough to recommend them, they're probably not complete scammers (but you guys will let me know if you find my Stack Exchange password anywhere online, right?).

So Mobizen actually does [work on Kit Kat without root](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8eEaJBvWb0). It's a little ad heavy, with ads in some weird places (like when you look for recordings inside the app, the first video it shows you is an ad, and you need to scroll down to find your recordings). So far, so good.