# Screen recording software for long (>20m, >4GiB) videos on (unrooted) Android

Tags: android, screen-recording

Similar question: [Screen record software for Android (unrooted Kit Kat)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39334/screen-record-software-for-android-unrooted-kit-kat)

I'm trying to record **1-hour livestreams** on Instagram that happen every 2 weeks or so. Instagram livestreams  can only be watched on mobile and, if the streamer chooses so, remain available to watch for 24 hours after the stream happens.

I'm currently using [AZ Screen Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free), however, **it single-handedly stops recording after about 20-25 minutes**. I don't get notified of this, it's just that when I press "Stop" after an hour or so the resulting video will be 20-25 minutes long and contain the first 20-25 minutes after I hit record (I guess I should be happy the file is not corrupted). I've noticed that many of my recordings are **exactly 4.00 GiB in size**, which hints to a [limitation due to using 32-bit numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869563/how-much-memory-can-be-accessed-by-a-32-bit-machine). My phone [is a 64-bit phone](https://www.droid-life.com/2016/02/21/samsung-galaxy-s7-and-galaxy-s7-edge-specs-official/), so maybe the limit is due to it having 4 GB RAM, but I don't believe that, as other apps also need to use RAM and because 4 GB usually means 3.something GiB. So it might just be a limitation in Android or poor programming.

So my current strategy is to make 3 separate 20-ish-minute recordings and edit them together on my PC, which is much more of a hassle than it sounds, because I don't have an SD card reader and my editing program is hard to use and likes to crash when exporting. Anyway, the resulting 1-hour file is usually under 4 GB in size, despite generous quality/bitrate settings (both in- and outputs are 1080p and the bitrate I chose was 8 Mbps). So I'm thinking it should be possible to find an app which can record the hole 1 hour and get the file size under 4 GiB (without me downgrading to 720p) or record beyond 4 GiB.

Additionally, my software doesn't allow me to record internal audio, so I just turn the phone's speakers on and record using the phone's microphone (I think this is called a "loopback"), which is very annoying too as everyone can hear it and the audio quality is suboptimal. I think this is actually an Android restriction that I can't get around without rooting?

Is there any software fitting my specific needs?